# Consistent Timezone in popup window

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

Using FullCalendar for my Google Calendar, I would like to ignore the local timezone completely and always render the time in America/Chicago time.

I'm actually not worried about the calendar itself - it works fine.  I'm trying to make the popup window display properly.  As long as I'm logged into a Google account, the time displays "local" time. But many of my visitors will not have Google accounts and when they open the popup window, it always displays GMT time.

How do I tell the popup window to always display "America/Chicago"? Is this a FullCalendar issue or a Google issue?

Comment: Is it really StackOverflow question?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of fullcalendar at:
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

You have the method/parameter timezone which allows you to set it with the parameter 'America/Chicago'

This is taken from their example:

```
function renderCalendar() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
                timezone: currentTimezone, //Here you can set timezone to 'America/Chicago'
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: {
                    url: 'php/get-events.php',
                    error: function() {
                        $('#script-warning').show();
                    }
                },
                loading: function(bool) {
                    $('#loading').toggle(bool);
                },
                eventRender: function(event, el) {
                    // render the timezone offset below the event title
                    if (event.start.hasZone()) {
                        el.find('.fc-title').after(
                            $('<div class="tzo"/>').text(event.start.format('Z'))
                        );
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

And accordingly the same parameter is available for the google calendar example:
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

Comment: Thanks! I had seen this, but actually couldn't get it to change. Turns out my google drive (where my calendar is hosted) wasn't running on my desktop and therefore not updating. I ended up just changing the event.url in the html to include + '&ctz=America/Chicago' and that did it too. I may go back and try editing the JavaScript now that I found my user error. Thanks again!